# loopbackjs/mongodb returning duplicate key error on bulk upsert operation

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, rest, loopbackjs

I'm trying to upsert multiple documents at once by using a PUT verb to a loopback based Rest API.
The body of the message contains an array of json objects.

```
[
   {"_id" : "1",
     "data" : "foo"
    },
     {"_id" : "2",
     "data" : "bar"
    }
]
```

On an empty database this works just fine (create). All documents are created as expected.
But if I run the same call again (update), I receive an error containing an array of similar error messages:

E11000 duplicate key error index: testdatabase.node.$*id* dup key: { : "1" }

After some further investigation, I found out that if I pass a single object, the upsert works fine.

```
{"_id" : "1",
     "data" : "foo"
}
```

BUT: if I pas an array with the same single object, the error is back.

```
[
    {"_id" : "1",
     "data" : "foo"
    }
]
```

Single upserts are not an option, because I have to update thousands of documents using the Rest Api.

loopback version: 2.22

Answer (score 0):

The `upsert` function takes a single model as a paramater.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-upsert).

In order to update different models as you want, you will have to use the native driver.

**EDIT**

I dug into loopback source code and found out that the `PUT` request uses the upsert function of the connector.
Which means that it expects one model and not an array, maybe loopback doesn't enforce it.
You can find the relevant code [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/lib/persisted-model.js#L546).

Anyway, the closest thing to upserting multiple models is the bulk operation of mongodb, but this leads to self implementation.

Comment: I partly agree. The documentation states "Update or insert a model instance". But that is applicable if I would have written a custom implementation. I just use the default "out of the box" PUT verb. The strange thing that I can pass an array of objects without problems on an empty database. Nevertheless the answer to my question will be the same. I will have to write my own implementation.  thks for your input.